# Help needed designing order and invoice in JavaEE shopping cart application

Tags: jakarta-ee, invoice

I got a bit confused designing the classes for a shopping cart application.

A `ShoppingCart` has a set of `ShopCartItem`s, each of which contains an instance of a `Product` and the quantity. The `ShoppingCart` instance is always stored in the session.

As shown below, `Invoice` has a reference to the `Customer`, a set of `ShopCartItem`s, date, invoice number, and total amount. How should I design the `Order` class? I'm thinking it should also contain the `Customer`, `ShopCartItem`s, and date.

I'm worried about creating redundant classes, but I want the functionality of letting a user cancel an order, so that requires storing them in the DB.

```
public class Invoice {
    private Long invoiceId;
    private Customer customer;
    private Set<ShopCartItem> shopCartItems;
    private Date invoiceDate;
    private int invoiceNum;
    private float totalAmount;
    private boolean isProcessed;
...
}

class Product{
    private String name;
    private double price;
    ...
}

class ShopCartItem{
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ton of experience with OO design, but here's my two cents:

I would move shopCartItems to `Order` and put a `Customer` reference and an `Invoice` reference there as well. `Invoice` could have a `Set<Order>` or a single reference and keep the other members it currently has (other than shopCartItems).

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I included the set of ShopCartItems because a description of products ordered need to be in the invoice along with price details

Comment: The Invoice would still have access to the list of ShopCartItems through Order.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the exact answer depends upon kind of relationship between invoice and order class. But let me assume 1 order will always have only 1 invoice generated. On the other hand, an invoice can be associated with many Orders.

Having assumed that you can have all customer data, shopcartItem etc present in both Order and Invoice classes but to avoid multiple instances of similar data, this is what you need to do:

1. Order should contain reference to associated Invoice. and then you can have a method in Order class : order.isInvoiceGenerated()
2. Order.addItem(ShopCartItem item) should add item to both Order class and Order's associated Invoice object.
3. There should n't be directly mutators for Invoice class for things like Customer/ShopcartItem object. So invoice.addItem(ShopCart item) should not be allowed.
4. Above 2 and 3 points will ensure that both Order and Invoice object are referencing same instance of Customer/ShopCartItem in memory. So it will keep them consistent.
5. Above design make sure that if you have changes in customer order, invoice needs to be re-generated. It customer cancel order, invoice also has to be canceled.

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: @markjason72: ur welcome. Let me know what is the exact solution you opted for.